# Angular 2 instantiate class with empty values

Tags: angular, typescript

How do you instantiate the members as class with empty values?

**[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/qBHZclhV0rUOz7lYNisS?p=preview)**

I instantiate with

`public members = new MemberClass();`

but the console shows Members: {} so I'm unable to set the default empty values

so basically I'm trying to replicate an empty structure like:

```
this.members = [ 
    { 
      "Name" : "", "Id" : "", "Team" : "",
      "Cases" : {
        "history" : []
      }
    }
];
```

Comment: You are using interface not class

Comment: @Jayakrishnan I've edited my question to reflect the class creation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use interfaces ;) And this is a way you can create an Array with an empty object of type `Member` with properties set. I don't know the use case, at least I do not set the properties for empty objects/arrays of models, but here we go :)

So first your interfaces, which are:

```
export interface Member {
    Id: string;
    Name: string;
    Cases: Case[];
}
export interface History {
    Id: string;
    CaseNumber: string;
}
export interface Case {
    History: History[];
}
```

Then you create 3 functions to set the properties:

```
export function createMember(Id?:string,Name?:string, Cases?:Case[]): Member {
  return {
    Id,
    Name,
    Cases[createCase()]       
  }
}

export function createCase(History?:History[]): Case {
  return {
    History[createHistory()]
  }
}

export function createHistory(Id?: string,CaseNumber?:string): History {
  return {
    Id,
    CaseNumber
  }
}
```

And now in your component you can call the function `createMember`, that then calls the two other functions:

```
members = [createMember()];
```

PS, according to your models, the following is not the model of `Member`-array, they name and build doesn't match, but I have created the above, based on the models you have provided.

Comment: could you create a plunkr? i seem to get `(SystemJS) Unexpected value 'AppComponent' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.` when I use your code

Comment: Sorry if I am being picky. Why the values are `undefined` instead of empty string values required in the original question?

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that you're using Interfaces there, not classes. In Typescript, as in Javascript, an empty object is just `{}`

So, to do what you're looking for, try this:
`let history: History = { Id:"", CaseNumber:""};`

If you try to leave out any of those properties, you'll get an error that they're required. If you want properties of an interface to be optional when instantiating, update your interface like this: `CaseNumber?: string;`

[Find more in the handbook.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html)

To further clarify: a class is a concrete type that you can instantiate and use as you would in any language. If you need a constructor or default values on your properties, you should use `export class MyType {}`.

However, in my experience, I've found interfaces in Typescript to be more useful than classes in many cases. The reason for this is that you can code against them at dev-time, but they aren't included in your bundles when you ship (N.B. this ENTIRELY depends on your use-case).

Comment: I've created http://plnkr.co/edit/qBHZclhV0rUOz7lYNisS?p=preview to have the class structure in separated files

Comment: where should I use `let history: History = { Id="", CaseNumber=""};` ? in the member.class.ts ?

Comment: @DanielS I think you're getting mixed up a little bit. A class is a concrete definition of a type. An interface is an outline, or a contract. Is the reason you need to create an instance of the class that you need a constructor? (`export class MyType` vs `export interface MyType` - the class will have a constructor, while the interface is a structure for you to code against and not an actual static type)

Comment: Correct syntax is `let history: History = { Id:"", CaseNumber:""};` (ie. replace `:` with `=`)

Comment: @Askanison4 i've added `src/member.class.ts` (forgot to before)

Comment: @Askanison4 so I need to change interface to class in all files? Yes, I would like to instantiate the class with default values (empty values)

Comment: @Askanison4 I've checked it now and I think I can use it to fit my needs better. But please could you take a look at http://plnkr.co/edit/qBHZclhV0rUOz7lYNisS?p=preview as I've modified the code but It seems I can't instantiate the class with empty values just yet. You can check the `console.log(this.members);` results only to see the structure of the class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143405/discussion-between-askanison4-and-daniel-s).

Comment: Hi. I have an issue here. I have put in a similar CaseNumber?: CaseNumberInterface; in my code. However, since the value takes time to load, javascript is throwing hard errors. It is all quiet when I have it as CaseNumber = {}; , but then I do get error notifications saying that the elements to which I had bound this by string interpolation in my html cant find it. What can I do?

Comment: I normally wrap any bindings where they won't be populated until after an async action with an *ngIf