# Issues mapping a HTTP response to a JSON and then mapping the JSON to a model

Tags: rest, angular

I am trying to map a http response to a JSON and then map part of that JSON to a Ticket interface as it has many values I don't need in my ticket interface.  My app compiles without any issues but when I test the REST function I get the below runtime error, I know the issue isn't with the backend as I'm able to successfully console log the response. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

```
My error:

    vendor.bundle.js:8137 Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
    main.bundle.js:553 TypeError: res.json(...).map is not a function
        at MapSubscriber.project (main.bundle.js:1330)
        at MapSubscriber._next (vendor.bundle.js:42853)
        at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (vendor.bundle.js:4709)
        at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (vendor.bundle.js:47289)
        at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.749.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.bundle.js:2478)
        at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.bundle.js:9228)
        at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.749.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.bundle.js:2477)
        at Zone.webpackJsonp.749.Zone.runTask (polyfills.bundle.js:2245)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (polyfills.bundle.js:2540)


My code:

    retrieveTicket(barcode: string) : Observable<any> {
          return this.http.get(`${this.API_URL}POS/RetrieveTicket/${barcode}`, this.options)
          .map((res: Response) => res.json().map(ticket => {          
                Object.assign({
                    ResponseCode: ticket.ResponseCode,
                    CustomError: ticket.CustomError,
                    ticketDate: ticket.POSTicket.Date,
                    ticketTime: ticket.POSTicket.EndTime,
                    cashierName: ticket.POSBarCode.POSCashier_Name,
                    tranNo: ticket.POSTicket.TranNo,
                    tranValue: ticket.POSTicket.ScanValue,
                    securityChecked: ticket.POSBarCode.SecurityChecked
                }) as ITicket})         
          )
          .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error || 'server error'));
      } 


 my interface:

        import { BaseRequestInterface } from './base-request.interface';

        export interface ITicket extends IBaseRequest {
            ticketDate: string;
            ticketTime: string;
            cashierName: string;
            tranNo: string;
            tranValue: string;
            timeSincePurchase: string;
            securityChecked: boolean;

            export function setTicket(obj?: any) {
                super();
                this.ResponseCode = obj && obj.ResponseCode || null;
                this.CustomError = obj && obj.CustomError || null;
                this.ticketDate = obj && obj.ticketDate || null;
                this.ticketTime = obj && obj.ticketTime || null;
                this.cashierName = obj && obj.cashierName || null;          
                this.tranNo = obj && obj.tranNo || null;
                this.tranValue = obj && obj.tranValue || null;
                this.timeSincePurchase = obj && obj.timeSincePurchase || null;
                this.securityChecked = obj && obj.securityChecked || null;
            }


        }

my BaseRequest Interface:

//  Base request class that returns from BRMService API
export interface IBaseRequest {
    //  Public properties available
     BaseURI?: string;
     CustomError?: string;
     ProviderName?: string;
     RequestFormData?: string;
     RequestURI?: string;
     ResponseCode?: number;    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:**

We learned that we are dealing with just one Object, rather than an array of object, so mapping the object to type `TicketModel` would be done like the following (shortened):

```ts
retrieveTicket(barcode: string) {
   return this.http.get(...)
     .map(res => res.json())
     .map(res => ({ResponseCode:res.ResponseCode, CustomError:res.CustomError}) as TicketModel)
}
```

The interface:

```ts
export interface TicketModel {
  ResponseCode: number; 
  CustomError:string 
}
```

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/IeW90S7iRcTnpEHwXPMI?p=preview)**

---

**ORIGINAL POST:**

Unclear if you are using a class or interface for your `TicketModel`, anyway I suggest you use an interface ;) Then you can simply map your incoming data like (shortened version):

```ts
.map((res:Response) => res.json().map(x => 
   Object.assign({ResponseCode: x.ResponseCode, 
                  CustomError:x.CustomError}) as TicketModel)))
```

If your response is an object with an array containing inside `items`, just add the `items` in:

```ts
.... res.json().items.map( ...
```

Comment: I added my ticketModel to the bottom of my question.  Any idea why it's not working with this model/giving me the undefined error?  Thanks for your effort...

Comment: You don't really need to use a class here, since you have class dependent functions. Just use an interface, that's my advice :) Also you are not exposing the properties in your class (`public`) If you insist on a class, you need to do something like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/BOaEx8njWV3oBNSVfegM What you are doing, using "return" in the mapping is redundant and that's why you are getting error at least for one reason. When you map, you don't need to use return :)

Comment: The main reason i'm using a class here is to be able to instansiate the ticketModel even though not all values are present.  Would it be possible to do this using a interface as well?

Comment: Yes you can... you can just declare a new object of type TicketModel `let ticket = <TicketModel>{}` This will of course not hold any properties. But if you really NEED them it's possible, but I see no reason why it should have to have the properties set. Interfaces do not exist on runtime, it's a contract. It helps IDE and programmer, IDE can warn you if you are trying to do something funky with your model. Classes are totally unnecessary if you don't have functions you need in the class. I'm pretty sure 95% of SO users here would give the advice to use interfaces instead ;)

Comment: Here's a example of creating properties to your model, so when you initialize a `TicketModel`, it would have the properties set: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43788669/6294072

Comment: thanks  for all your time/effort.  I added my converted interface at the bottom of my question, does that look correct?  also when deriving from IBaserequest can I just add a ? to make every member of IBaseRequest optional?  e.g. CustomError?: string;

Comment: I changed the code in my answer to use a interface but now getting the error that res.json().map is not a function...  Any idea what's going on?

Comment: How does your JSON look like? is it `{"items":[..]}` or `[....]`? Then it depends on the map like I put in the answer, if there is items, then it needs to be `res.json().items.map`, if the response is just an array, it should be `res.json().map`. Also, have you imported `map`? `import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`

Comment: my response JSON isn't an array, it's a TicketMessage object which consist of many unnecessary values which is why i'm trying to map just those items I need to the interface.  Yes I did import map, there's many other rest calls that use it but this is the first time i' trying this approach.

Comment: Okay, THEN we need to map it completely differently, the above is for an array, because I thought it was an array of tickets based on your attempt in your question. Hold on, I'll update my answer in a while, am just in the midst of something else. I'll let you know! :)

Comment: @user2094257 Updated my answer :)

Comment: @AJT_82: I face nearly the same issue which I just can't solve. Can I add my code as new question (I'am trying to avoid duplicated questions)? As a comment it would be too long? Error I get is: `vendor.8a90b3118eccd4545555.bundle.js:1 ERROR TypeError: t.json(...).map is not a function`