# Can't map HTTP response to Interface

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-material2

The following code returns on Chrome console: `ERROR TypeError: t.json(...).map is not a function` The `ng serve -prod` and `ng test --sm=false` runs fine.

I want to map the result to the model in Interface, and output them in HTML.

```
....
export interface UsersData {
   _id: number;
   email: string;
   fullName: string;
}
export class RetrieveUsrData {
    private issuesUrl = 'http://localhost:4000/users';
    getUserDetails(): Observable<UsersData[]> {
      return this.http.get(this.issuesUrl)
                      .map(this.extractData)
    }

    extractData(result: Response): UsersData[] {
        console.log(JSON.stringify( result.json()) );
        return result.json().map(usr => {
            return {
                _id: usr.message._id,
                email: usr.message.email,
                fullName: usr.message.fullName
            }
        }).subscribe(result => result = result);
    }
    constructor(private http: Http) {}
}
...
```

I have been checking in few issues e.g. [mapping a HTTP response to a JSON and then mapping the JSON to a model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44286315/issues-mapping-a-http-response-to-a-json-and-then-mapping-the-json-to-a-model), and changed my code/method to:

```
extractData(result: Response): UsersData[] {
    return result.json().map(res => ({
        _id:res.message._id,
        email:res.message.email,
        fullName:res.message.fullName
    }) as UsersData)
    .subscribe(result => result = result); ;
}
```

but I keep getting the same error.

Comment: what is the response from `http://localhost:4000/users` API

Comment: @PankajParkar: This is the Response of `http://localhost:4000/users` API:
`{ "error": false, "message": [ { "_id": "523", "email": "xxxxx@foo.de", "fullName": "xxxx yyyyy" }, { "_id": "594", "email": "xxxxx@foo.de", "fullName": "xxxx yyyyy" }, { "_id": "88", "email": "xxxxx@foo.de", "fullName": "xxxx yyyyy"}, {"_id": "59", "email": "xxxxx@foo.de", "fullName": "xxxx yyyyy"} ] }`. But it's fixed now. Thanks!

Comment: I thought the same. @Fenton already answered it, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.map` method is available on arrays, not objects.

The most likely cause of your error is that if you have a response like this:

```
{
    someKey: [1, 2, 3, 4]
}
```

You will need to use:

```
result.json().someKey.map( //...
```

And you may even be able to simply use the following if the JSON actually adheres to your interface:

```
return <UsersData[]>result.json().someKey;
```

Comment: here is my Response: `{
    "error": false,
    "message": [
        { "_id": "523", "email": "xxxxx@foo.de", "fullName": "xxxx yyyyy" },
        { "_id": "594", "email": "xxxxx@foo.de", "fullName": "xxxx yyyyy" },
        { "_id": "88", "email": "xxxxx@foo.de", "fullName": "xxxx yyyyy"},
        {"_id": "59", "email": "xxxxx@foo.de", "fullName": "xxxx yyyyy"}
]
}`

Comment: Great! my Bad. Just missed to catch the `message` key in my JSON response. As you said, the `map()` must be executed on `Arrays`.  So, in my Response `message` is an Array of objects. Saved my day.

Comment: A question please. What would be the best approach to pass the value of the key `_id` from the JSON object to other component. Would it be: `@Input()  _id` or using a kind of service for that would be the solution? Thanks.