# angular2 - create a new nested object in form

Tags: forms, angular, object, nested

I get the following error when rendering a form in my Angular2 web. This component is used to create a new nested object, therefore is an empty form.

The issue occurs in the nested parameters of the object. The departureDate falls right under trip (trip.departureDate), therefore it works in the browser. Because "city" is nested inside "from" (newTrip.from.city) I get the error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'city' of undefined
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]

html:

```
    <h3>NEW TRIP </h3>
    <div class="field">
      <h6>Departure: </h6>
      <input ngui-datetime-picker name="departureDateTime" [(ngModel)]="newTrip.departureDateTime" required>
    </div>
    <div class="field marginTop">
      <h6>From: </h6>
      <label for="newTrip">City: </label>
      <input type="text"  name="fromcity" [(ngModel)]="newTrip[from].city" required>
      <label for="newTrip">Country: </label>
      <input type="text" name="fromCountry" [(ngModel)]="newTrip[from].country" required>
    </div>

    <div class="field marginTop">
      <h6>Arrival: </h6>
      <input ngui-datetime-picker name="arrivalDateTime" [(ngModel)]="newTrip.arrivalDateTime" required>
    </div>
```

component.ts (I initialize the var "newTrip" with the "Trip" model):

```
export class NewTripComponent implements OnInit {
   newTrip: Trip = new Trip();
   error: string;
```

trip model:

```
    export class Trip {
    _id: string;
    owner: string;
    from: {
        city: string;
        country: string;
        lat: number;
        lng: number;
    };
    to: {
        city: string;
        country: string;
        lat: number;
        lng: number;
    };
    departureDateTime: Date;
    arrivalDateTime: Date;
    bag: {
        restrictions: Array<string>;
        weight: number;
        dimensions: {
            high: number;
            width: number;
        }  
    }
  }
```

Comment: Use ngModel like [(ngModel)]="newTrip.from.city"

Comment: I also tried... It was my first option. Did not work

Comment: You could also go with interfaces and do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43788669/6294072

Answer (score 0):

you have to know that : `newTrip[from]` is `undefined` , that's why you can not get the city from it.
as solution you can create a class called Place that contains :

```
class Place{
    city: string;
    country: string;
    lat: number;
    lng: number;
}
```

and in your class Trip :

```
from: Place = new Place();
to : Place = new Place();
```

Hope it helps you